# findViewById from AlertDialog (with Custom Layout) - NullPointerException

Tags: android

I’m trying to get the text out of EditTexts within an AlertDialog, which is created as you can see below. The problem is, that I can’t retrieve the textviews. All I get is a null-value. Any ideas?

```
    final EditText editFirstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirstname);
    final EditText editLastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLastname);

    bttAddPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            builder.setView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_player, null))
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            databaseHelper.addPlayer(editFirstname.getText().toString(),editLastname.getText().toString());
                            playerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: We need a stacktrace. One of the EditText variables is null.

Comment: They are both null. But why? I typed in the field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to search inside of the View that you inflate for your Alert dialog, say that the view you inflate is as follows:

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_player, container);
```

then you would need to do

```
EditText editFirstName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editFirstName);
EditText editLastName  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editLastName);
```

It looks like right now you are trying to instantiate a variable for something that does not exist, you have no reference of where the `EditText` is actually located, it's trying to look inside of the current view, which does not contain the `EditText`.